# SQL if field length is less then 10 symbols search via like without %%

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can i do, that if my field in db is less then 10 symbols, search via non strong like, but if more than 10, than with %% options? 
So how to check field length?

My code in ruby is such:

```
@search = CrossList.find(:all, :conditions => ['cross_value like ? ', oem_condition])
```

But how to do something like:

```
@search = CrossList.find(:all, :conditions => ['length(cross_value) < 10 and cross_value like ? ', oem_condition])
```

else

```
 @search = CrossList.find(:all, :conditions => ['length(cross_value) >= 10 and cross_value like %?% ', oem_condition])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two conditions, and `OR` them together:

```
@search = CrossList.find(:all, :conditions => [
   "(length(cross_value) >= 10 AND cross_value like CONCAT('%',?,'%')) OR (length(cross_value) < 10 AND cross_value like ?) ",
    oem_condition,
    oem_condition
])
```

The `LENGTH()` condition must be met by one of the two `()` groups, and whichever is met will also require that the `LIKE` condition with which it is `AND`'d will be applied.

Comment: something bad Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%'A210466'%) OR (length(cross_value) < 12 AND cross_value like 'A210466') )' at line 1: SELECT `cross_lists`.* FROM `cross_lists`  WHERE ((length(cross_value) >= 12 AND cross_value like %'A210466'%) OR (length(cross_value) < 12 AND cross_value like 'A210466') )

Comment: @ValdisAzamaris Add the `CONCAT()` as above, sorry.

Comment: i just need to set ? in ()

Comment: @ValdisAzamaris It will work either as `CONCAT('%',?,'%')` or by placing `'%#{oem_condition}%'` as the array parameter.